# AWS EC2 Spot Instances cancelled before fulfillment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I am trying to bring up multiple AWS EC2 Spot instances, machine type "m3.medium" or ""m4.2xlarge" in REGION="eu-west-1".

I am able to bring up On-Demand instances but my spots keep failing. Below is the error. Has anyone seen this before or worked around it?

[image]

Comment: Have you contacted Amazon?

Comment: Did you bid for a price above the value in the following doc https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/pricing/ ?

Comment: Use `aws ec2 describe-spot-instance-requests`.  There is a `Status->Message` element there, that this isn't visible here.  It may contain an explanation.

Comment: Fixed this thanks! Apparently my limit was not set correctly on AWS side.